# How can I create a relation between entities twice

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, entities

I am trying to create some sort of Inventory:

*(The following Code is obviously not complete)*

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Item", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="character_inventory_mm",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="item_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $inventory;

    //etc
}
```

My Problem is that a User can have the same Item twice or even more often.
Is there a way to tell Doctrine not to create unique keys on those Relations or do I have to create some sort of mapping entity?

Something like:

```
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Item", fetch="EAGER", indexBy="NULL")
```

I have looked up doctrines joinTable and joinColumns and ManytoMany Documentation but I did not find a way to "fix" my Issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would need an unique key to differentiate multiple items connected to the same user.

Just create UserItems entity with a primary key and correspoding OneToMany and ManyToOne relations.